# How to sort a table by column in jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a data table with 1000 rows with data as follows

```
+--------+-----+--------+------------+
|  Name  | Age |  Sex   | Occupation |
+--------+-----+--------+------------+
| Eric   |  23 | Male   | Student    |
| Ryan   |  64 | Male   | Teacher    |
| Jessy  |  22 | Female | Student    |
| Kyle   |  52 | Male   | Teacher    |
| Goerge |  23 | Male   | Student    |
+--------+-----+--------+------------+
```

Now, I want to segregate data with accordance of Occupation, Eg. If user selects 
Student occupation, then data table should show rows only of that of students.

How can I do this?

Till now, I have gone through the documentation of data table, but haven't found anything that can help me with this ^

Comment: "*I have gone through the documentation*" Apparently you missed **https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html**